# Send user to their email client

Tags: angularjs, email

I recently was on twitter and needed to reset my password. When click send to send your email a reset password, it routes you to another url with a button saying "Go to my email"

[image]

I am using AngularJs and want to be able to use this feature of having user click a button to go to their email client! That is so cool! I cannot find any examples or documentation on how to do this. Any ideas on how you could  send a user to their specific email client AngularJs?

The only way I could see of achieving this would be writing a controller that would have some information like this: "if email ends in @gmail.com = route to 'https://www.gmail.com'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: 1. Create a link, as you mention, to the appropriate client based on the email address, or 2. Use a `mailto` link, which will open the user's default email client. So, it really depends on your use case to choose the appropriate method.

In terms of the link to the email, you can either create a map of email address and urls:

```
{
  'gmail.com': 'https://www.gmail.com',
  ...
}
```

Or, you could probably get away with splitting the string at the `@` and just tacking `www.` to the front of it to serve as a link.

Other than that, the browser gives you no other method.

Comment: Thanks for the input!